# Why is the str() used in this situation?

Tags: python, django

These are the codes from [django.db.models.fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/_modules/django/db/models/fields/)

```
__all__ = [str(x) for x in (
    'AutoField', 'BLANK_CHOICE_DASH', 'BigAutoField', 'BigIntegerField',
    'BinaryField', 'BooleanField', 'CharField', 'CommaSeparatedIntegerField',
    'DateField', 'DateTimeField', 'DecimalField', 'DurationField',
    'EmailField', 'Empty', 'Field', 'FieldDoesNotExist', 'FilePathField',
    'FloatField', 'GenericIPAddressField', 'IPAddressField', 'IntegerField',
    'NOT_PROVIDED', 'NullBooleanField', 'PositiveIntegerField',
    'PositiveSmallIntegerField', 'SlugField', 'SmallIntegerField', 'TextField',
    'TimeField', 'URLField', 'UUIDField',
)]
```

I think `str(x) for x in (...)` and `x for x in (...)` are the same in this situation. **Why is the str() used?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note the `from __future__ import unicode_literals` at the top of the code.
Every string literal will be a unicode string by default now (like it is already in Python 3).

```
>>> from __future__ import unicode_literals
>>> s = 'test'
>>> type(s)
<type 'unicode'>
```

In order to avoid the `TypeError` mentioned in the comment

```
# Avoid "TypeError: Item in ``from list'' not a string" -- unicode_literals
# makes these strings unicode
```

all the unicode literals in the tuple `('AutoField', 'BLANK_CHOICE_DASH', ...)` are converted to Python 2 bytestrings.

You are right that the list comprehension would be completely pointless (in both versions of Python) if the `import` statement at the top was not there.